# How to change QueryFilter run time?

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

i want to change `QueryFilter` run time, so i call `OnModelCreating` function but it doesn't work .

in DbContext class :

```cs
private static ModelBuilder myModelBuilder;

private static ParsysDbContext _myParsysDbContext ;

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {

     modelBuilder.Entity<Page>().HasQueryFilter(q => q.Languge.Language_Name == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

      myModelBuilder = modelBuilder;

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

public static void OnModelCreatingCall()
{

      _myParsysDbContext.OnModelCreating(myModelBuilder);

}
```

Comment: Filters are part of the model and can't be changed. However, you can alternate between models at runtime by using [`IModelCacheKeyFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model).

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? What is your current result and your expected result?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your expected result and your current query.

If you want to query `Page`, and only return the `Page` which contains the `Languge.Language_Name` with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name`, you could try query like below:

```
var result1 = context.Page.Include(p => p.Languge).ToList();
```

If you want to query `Languge` and only return `Languge` with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name`, you need to set `HasQueryFilter` on `Languge` like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Languge>().HasQueryFilter(q => q.Language_Name == CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
```